# When is `CHARACTER SET` included in a column definition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

### Description

To test our updates, we compare an old, updated database schema with a fresh installation. The two schemas should be identical.

We use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to find the differences. However, we noticed that with MySQL 8 we find some differences based on how the tables were constructed. Some columns include `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, while others do not.

### How to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    col1 VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(1024) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
);
SHOW CREATE TABLE t1;
```

and the output:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `col1` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I tried to figure out what's different about the two columns, but they look absolutely identical:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE table_schema = "db" AND table_name = "t1";

                          col1                               col2
                          -----                              ----
           TABLE_CATALOG: def                                def 
            TABLE_SCHEMA: db                                 db
              TABLE_NAME: t1                                 t1
             COLUMN_NAME: col1                               col2
        ORDINAL_POSITION: 1                                  2
          COLUMN_DEFAULT:
             IS_NULLABLE: NO                                 NO
               DATA_TYPE: varchar                            varchar
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: 1024                               1024
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: 4096                               4096
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: NULL                               NULL
           NUMERIC_SCALE: NULL                               NULL 
      DATETIME_PRECISION: NULL                               NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: utf8mb4                            utf8mb4
          COLLATION_NAME: utf8mb4_unicode_ci                 utf8mb4_unicode_ci
             COLUMN_TYPE: varchar(1024)                       varchar(1024)
              COLUMN_KEY:
                   EXTRA:
              PRIVILEGES: select,insert,update,references    select,insert,update,references
          COLUMN_COMMENT:
   GENERATION_EXPRESSION:
                  SRS_ID: NULL                               NULL
```

### Question

How do those columns differ? They both use the character set `utf8mb4` and the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Is it just a flag somewhere? And what would that flag do?

Comment: "What changed between MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8", see releasnotes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/

Comment: "Why is CHARACTER SET ... shown?"   What was the exact `ALTER TABLE` statement you used. When a character set was specified doing a change to a column definition, then it might be stored.

Comment: BTW: To what exact version of 8.0 are you upgrading? [8.0.29](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-29.html) has a bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 8.0.11 changed the behavior of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. It now shows the collation and character set if they have been explicitly specified. (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46239)

For this, each column remembers if it has been explicitly assigned a collation or character set. The relevant code can be found in [`store_create_info`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8d8c986e5716e38cb776b627a8eee9e92241b4ce/sql/sql_show.cc#L1981):

```cpp
/*
  For string types dump charset name only if field charset is same as
  table charset or was explicitly assigned.
 */
if (field->charset() != share->table_charset ||
    column_has_explicit_collation) {
    packet->append(STRING_WITH_LEN(" CHARACTER SET "));
    packet->append(field->charset()->csname);
}
```

(NB: I believe the comment is wrong.)

The columns are exactly the same otherwise. I believe this is done to make the code created by `SHOW CREATE TABLE` portable to databases that use other default charsets and collations.

Answer (score 0):

You should read MySQL's excellent [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html) which explains the difference between character sets and collations.  Character sets determine which characters can be stored in a column or table, while collations determine how characters are compared against each other.  Here again is your column definition:

```sql
col1 VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

This means that `utf8mb4` characters can be stored in `col1`.  However, it provides `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as the collation, which is case *insensitive*.  This means that comparing e.g. `m` and `M` would result in both characters being the same for sorting and other operations.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the difference between character sets and collations. What I do not understand is  the difference between `col1` and `col2`. They both have character set `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. So why is the character set included in the definition of one column and not for the other?

Comment: I don't know, but I'll comment that a character set can have more than one collation.

Comment: I was able to significantly simplify my question above, but I still do not understand what the difference between the two columns is.